# Testing Rails app with Rspec using declarative authorizations helper method permitted_to?

Tags: ruby, testing, ruby-on-rails-3.1, integration-testing, rspec2

I am trying to test a rails engine with rspec where I am using the declarative_authorization gem to manage the roles for my users. UserSessions are managed by Authlogic.

In my test I call a helper method which is rendering a view partial.
In that partial i am using the `permitted_to? do ... end` method of declarative authorization.

My expection is to get a response with a html string.

The problem is that `permitted_to?` throws an Exception:

undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #

I took a closer look into declarative auths AuthorizationInController module (which requires the authorization.rb where the current_user method is defined as a class method) and found that the current_user method is getting called from options_for_permit which is called from permitted_to?.

When I change `:user => current_user` in the options_for_permit method to `:user => Authorization.current_user` the exception is gone and my test passes.

I am not a very well skilled Rubyist, so i dont know if that is the correct way of fixing that problem. The method permitted_to? is a fundamental method of declarative_authorization, so I dont know why it is working when normally using it and not when using it here in the test.

my questions:

- Is this a bug in declarative authorization?
- Could my fix make impact on other areas?

Hopefully waiting for your response...

Thanks
robin

EDIT:

I just noticed that my application does not work correctly anymore with my changes in development environment.

Authorization.current_user is now an Authorization::AnonymousUser
while current_user is a valid User with the admin role...

Stubbing current_user does not work, that was what i tried at first.

My test code:

```
it "should render the main navi for all core modules" do
  main_navi = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, "../..", "config/alchemy", "modules.yml"))
  helper.stub(:alchemy_modules).and_return(main_navi)
  Authorization.current_user = Factory(:admin_user)
  helper.admin_main_navigation.should have_selector('a.main_navi_entry')
end
```

view code which should get rendered:

```
<%- permitted_to?(
  :index,
  :admin
) do -%>
...
<%- end -%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not have a `current_user`, that is what `declarative_authorization` expects.

Try to log in with authlogic:

```
before(:each) do
    activate_authlogic
    UserSession.create Factory(:admin_user)
end
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: I already used authlogic in my first tries... but declarative autorization does not get that current user when using `permitted_to?`

The Exception is the same:
undefined local variable or method `current_user'